# Rails local_assign vs. local variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, local

Learning from the [Rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables), I don't understand how `local_assign` works below:

> To pass a local variable to a partial in only specific cases use the
>   local_assigns.
>
> - index.html.erb
>
>   ```
>   <%= render user.articles %>
>   ```
> - show.html.erb
>
>   ```
>   <%= render article, full: true %>
>   ```
> - _articles.html.erb
>
>   ```
>   <h2><%= article.title %></h2>
>
>   <% if local_assigns[:full] %>
>     <%= simple_format article.body %>
>   <% else %>
>     <%= truncate article.body %>
>   <% end %>
>   ```
>
> This way it is possible to use the partial without the need to declare
>   all local variables.

How is the partial even being rendered by the show action when it has the name `_articles`, which will only show for the index action? I also don't see why you use add the option of `full: true` when you could have just used `locals: {full:true}`. What's the difference?

Comment: There is no practical difference between `render: locals: {full:true}` and `render full: true` they both assign a local variable named `full` the latter is just a newer shorthand.

Comment: Regarding your first question, the name `_articles` is a typo. The partial name should be `_article`. I've opened a [pull request to fix the guide](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27896)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regarding the use of `local_assigns`:

The point of this section of the guide is to show how to access  *optional* locals in your partials. If a local variable name `full` may *or may not* be defined inside your partial, simply accessing `full` will cause an error when the local is not defined.

You have two options with *optional* locals:

First, using `local_assigns[:variable_name]`, which will be `nil` when the named local wasn't provided, or the value of the variable.

Second, you can use `defined?(variable_name)` which will be `nil` when the variable is not defined, or truthy (the string `"local_variable"`) when the local *is* defined.

Using `defined?` is simply a guard against accessing an undefined variable, you will still have to actually *access* the variable to get its value:

- `if local_assigns[:full]`
- `if defined?(full) && full`

As for your specific questions:

> How is the partial even being rendered by the show action when it has the name _articles, which will only show for the index action?

[This is a typo](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27896). The correct partial name is `_article.html.erb`. Regardless of the action, `index` or `show`, the correct partial name is the *singular* of the model. In the case of rendering a collection of models (as in index.html.erb), the partial should still be singularly named.

> I also don't see why you use add the option of `full: true` when you could have just used `locals: {full:true}`. What's the difference?

The point is that the `full: true` syntax is shorter. You have two identical options:

- `render partial: @article, locals: { full: true }`
  or
- `render @article, full: true`.

The second is significantly shorter and less redundant.